# Printing output of Collection.Max

Tags: java, collections

I have the following code . Collections.Max returns the  . How can I show the value of string and integer no By System.out.println() ?

```
public class SortMapOnKeyExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("sultan");
        list.add("Masum");
        list.add("sultan");
        list.add("Sorry");
        list.add("sultan");
        list.add("Masum");
        list.add("sultan");
        list.add("Tarek");
        list.add("sultan");

        Set<String> uniques = new HashSet(list);
        Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String elem : uniques)
        {
            counts.put(elem, Collections.frequency(list, elem));
        }

        Collections.max(counts.entrySet(), new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1, Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
                return (o1.getValue() - o2.getValue());
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I have tried a lot But could not find out how can I do this ?please help me . The purpose of this code is to find the string that is occurred maximum and also its index ?

Comment: you see, more than one element may have the max counts

Comment: after getting the counts, I think you have to iterate on the map to get the elements that have the max count. I don't think you can do it inside the comparator (if that was your idea)

Comment: @BoristheSpider , can you edit the code in an efficient manner ?

Comment: How can I iterate over counts ?

Comment: @BoristheSpider , I do not understand how to store the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you code will run in `O(n^2)` time - each call to `Collections.frequency` must loop over the entire data, and this is done once for every element. You can easily make this `O(n)`:

```
final Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
for (final String s : list) {
    final Integer c = counts.get(s);
    if (c == null) {
        counts.put(s, 1);
    } else {
        counts.put(s, c + 1);
    }
}
```

Now note that you can have *more than one* item with the same count. You need to *sort* the entries by value and then print the top ones:

```
final List<Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<>(counts.entrySet());
Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(final Entry<String, Integer> o1, final Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o2.getValue(), o1.getValue());
    }
});
final MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat("{0} has a count of {1,number,integer}");
final Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> iter = entries.iterator();
final Entry<String, Integer> first = iter.next();
System.out.println(format.format(new Object[]{first.getKey(), first.getValue()}));
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    final Entry<String, Integer> entry = iter.next();
    if (entry.getValue() != first.getValue()) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(format.format(new Object[]{entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()}));
}
```

First we create a `List` from the `entrySet()` of the `Map`. Next we sort the `List` - notice the reversed order of the comparison - this means the sort is in descending rather than ascending order. Also note the use of `Integer.compare`, this is because using `a - b` to compare is very bad practice as it will overflow if `a` is large and `b` is large and negative; while not a problem here it is not a good habit to get into.

Now we take as `Iterator` of the `List` and keep printing out elements until we encounter one that is not equal to (must be less than) the count of the first element.

Output:

```
{sultan=5, Sorry=1, Tarek=1, Masum=2}
sultan has a count of 5
```

With different data, where we add `Test` five times also the output becomes:

```
{Test=5, sultan=5, Sorry=1, Tarek=1, Masum=2}
Test has a count of 5
sultan has a count of 5
```

Comment: thanks Boris . It helps me a lot . I cant express my gratitude in words . Hope you will get reward for this help

Comment: @osimerpothe my pleasure, glad the code helped you.

Comment: I have spent almost a day for this purpose . Have a great day the genious .